# Why doesn't Bourbon work with Takana?

Tags: html, css, compiler-errors, sass, bourbon

So I am using this awesome package for Sublime Text Editor called **Takana** that compiles my SASS instantly as I am making changes. While I am able to compile my **Bourbon mixins** and then see the changes I am not able to use it with Takana so that it compiles instantly and I see the changes imminently. Does anyone know why that is? Any information will be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

**Extra Information:**

I am using the latest version of Bourbon and I believe Takana as well since I just installed it this week.

> UPDATE

**How I include Bourbon:**

I tried including Bourbon 2 different ways at the top of my style.scss

1. @import "bourbon/bourbon";
2. @import "bourbon/_bourbon.scss";

both ways did not work with Takana.. meaning it did work if I refreshed the page but NOT with Takana (instantly).

Comment: How are you `@include`'ing Bourbon?

Comment: Also just incase you meant how I am using the mixins I would do something basic like `@include linear-gradient(#1e5799, #2989d8);`